# Positioning multiple images at the bottom and keep it responsive

Tags: html, css

So all i want to do is position these 3 images on the bottom of the screen and keep them inline with text at the bottom, this is going to be a portal page.

```
<!--Main portal-->
        <div id="portal-logo">
            <img id="logo-image" src="Images/logo.png"></img>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="portal-images col-md-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/chest.png" hspace="20"></img></a>
                <span class="caption">STORE</span>
            </div>

            <div class="portal-images col-md-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/key.png" hspace="20"></img></a>
                <span class="caption">VOTE</span>
            </div>

            <div class="portal-images col-md-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/chest.png" hspace="20"></img></a>
                <span class="caption">STORE</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--Portal end-->
```

I was wondering what am i doing wrong, i am a newbie web developer and not as skillfull yet ;)

here's my css,

```css
#logo-image{
 position: absolute;
   top: 35%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   max-width: 400px;

}
.portal-images {
 text-align: center;
}
.portal-images img {
 -webkit transition: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: 0.5s;
 -o-transition: 0.5s;
 transition: 0.5s;

}
.portal-images img:hover {
 margin-top: -100px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px yellow;
}
.caption {
 font-family: 'open sans';
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 300;
}
```

Thanks :)!

Comment: screenshot please? the code snippet isn't running and I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Side note, images are self-closing. There is no `</img>` tag. That, and the `hspace` attribute disappeared decades ago.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/119f79cbacfcb27a66f96e5e1da60886 There you go, all i want is those 3 images with the text to go to the bottom, i tryed margin-top: 600px but that makes it look weird on mobile cause it spaces all images with 600px :/

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know im just trying everything i can :P

Comment: Provide us the correct code. You can make an snippet in S.O. or make a http://jsfiddle.net that allows you to reproduce the problem and we can help you ASAP. See more: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/